# Best way to use Memory (joblib) with different user accounts?

Tags: python, joblib

Using the Memory function of joblib to cache some functions in a shared folder leads to Problems.

```
from joblib import Memory

Memory('/tmp/some_folder')
```

The folder will be created write only for the active user. Logging in with another user account on ubuntu results in the error message:

```
  File "/home/my_folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 937, in __init__
    **backend_options))
  File "/home/my_folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 131, in _store_backend_factory
    backend_options=backend_options)
  File "/home/my_folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_store_backends.py", line 400, in configure
    mkdirp(self.location)
  File "/home/my_folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/disk.py", line 61, in mkdirp
    os.makedirs(d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/some_folder'
```

I can of course change the access rights manually, but what is the best way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this Problem by myself changing the user mask before running memory:

```
umask = os.umask(0)  # switch user mask to root
Memory('/tmp/some_folder')
os.umask(umask)      # switch user mask back
```